# How to know all the JS file dependencies using JS code?

Tags: javascript

**My main use-case is to know all the JS file dependencies!**

If I have file `a.js` that define a function `foo`, and another file `b.js` that call the function `foo`, I want to know that `b.js -> a.js` where `->` means that `b.js` depend on `a.js`.

*Is it possible? Can someone think of a tricky solution for that?*

I have tried to override the foo function and get the stack call, and it works fine, I know that `b.js` call `foo`, but I still do not know that `foo` was defined in `a.js`...

**So maybe someone can think of a solution for this:**

I have a file named "a.js" that define a global function `foo`.

And, I have a file named "b.js" that includes code that gets all the non-native functions on the `window` object, so here I got the global function `foo`.

Now, for each non-native global functions, I want to know the JS file name that defines them, so here for `foo` I want to get "a.js"

*Is it possible? Can someone think of a tricky solution for that?*

**Note:** I need to run it in the browser, **Not using** Node.js. And, **not all** the file are mine, so I can't edit them.

Comment: Presumably "using JS code" means that answers dependent on a browser's GUI debugging tool are unacceptable?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. And I can't think of a situation where that would be necessary.

Comment: Can I ask why you are attempting to do this?

Comment: A browser extension might be able to do this, but other than that I would say that this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I need it to be in JS code... I can't use the GUI debugging tool in the browser...

Comment: Add a console.log(window) behind every script, then you know when it is set

Comment: You need to store the names of the globals at the end of a.js to an array, and create a similar array in b.js. Then you could compare the arrays. Not a clean way, but probably the only possible.

Comment: But not all the scripts are mine in my website..

Comment: What is the use-case? I can't imagine any ...

Comment: You're trying to discover something that browsers simply do not keep track of. You could add a script that you include after every other script and have it update a catalog of global symbols, but that seems like a really odd thing to do. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Editing the Question...

Comment: See now... This is the problem

Comment: @Pointy They might not keep track of the assignment to the global variable, but they do keep a source reference on every function object. Which of course is inaccessible to in-page-js…

Answer (score 0):

Run this code first, and check the call stack in debugger.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
  set: function() {
    debugger;
  }
});
```

Comment: With code like this I managed to get to b.js file name, but I want the a.js file name, where the foo function was defined...

Comment: If you run this before the `a.js` is executed, the debugger will stop when `foo` is declared in `a.js`

Comment: OK, but I need to know about foo for this solution, and in my real world, I don't know about foo... can it be a more generic solution?

Comment: It is not the right solution, I can't use this because it doesn't work on functions that I declare like this function foo(){}. And it doesn't work also because I want it to be generic solution where I don't know about foo function, I want it to work on all the global functions